# Стилизация drawer

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы над Listview у выдвижной панели была картинка, а не сразу сверху начинался ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно сделать с помощью двух layout'ов. Первый:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

И второй, drawer_header.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gas_st"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Только в этом случае под картинкой не `ListView`, а меню из menu/drawer.xml:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/first_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/item_1" />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/second_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/item_2" />
</group>
```

Но можно попробовать заменить меню `ListView`, если нужен именно этот элемент.